# Mysql - Run the nex AND Condition if first one is TRUE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

Here is my code :

```
SELECT *
FROM (`View_Products_With_Category`)
WHERE `category_id` =  '47'
AND `top_id` =  0
AND (select count(product_id) from Modules where product_id=`View_Products_With_Category`.id)= 0
ORDER BY `order`, `sub_order`, `code`
```

This query returns 8 rows from 15.000 records. My problem is that (select count(product_id) from Modules where product_id=`View_Products_With_Category`.id)= 0 line works so slow.

I need a syntax to let work the slow line if the first condition is TRUE.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but in your particular case it's better to transform subquery to `JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`

Try this:

```
SELECT V.*
FROM View_Products_With_Category V
LEFT JOIN Modules M ON V.id = M.product_id
WHERE V.category_id =  '47' AND V.top_id =  0 AND M.product_id IS NULL
ORDER BY V.order, V.sub_order, V.code
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `left join` and check if the join worked with `is null`.

```
SELECT v.*
FROM `View_Products_With_Category` v
LEFT JOIN modules ON m.product_id= v.id
WHERE v.`category_id` =  '47'
AND v.`top_id` =  0
AND m.product_id IS NULL
ORDER BY v.`order`, v.`sub_order`, v.`code`
```

See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)